# Showing that $\frac{1}{2^n +1} + \frac{1}{2^n +2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\geq 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, harmonic-numbers

> Show that $$\frac{1}{2^n +1} + \frac{1}{2^n +2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\geq \frac{1}{2}$$ for all $n\geq 1$

I need this in order to complete my proof that $1 + \frac{n}{2} \leq H_{2^n}$, but I don't have any ideas.

I know it is true at least for the first $20$ cases, but I can't prove it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** for every $1\leq k\leq 2^n$
$$\frac{1}{2^n+k}\geq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} $$

do every term in your sum is greater then $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} $ and in the sum there is $2^n$ terms so  your sum is greater then $2^n$ times $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} $  $\cdots$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: how many summands are there? What is the smallest summand?

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^n+k} \geq \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^n+2^n} =\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$
the rightmost sum equals $\frac{1}{2}$, in fact we have a strict inequality.

Answer (score 2):

First, see that this sum has $2^n$ terms. Then, $\forall k\in \{1,\dots,2^n\}$, you have $\frac{1}{2^n+k}\geq\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.

Summing these inequalities, you get the result.

Answer (score 1):

This answer addresses this part (really the *main* part) of your question:

> I need this in order to complete my proof that $1 + \frac{n}{2} \leq H_{2^n}$, but don't have any ideas.

Consider the following exercise, the solution of which answers your question directly (skip ahead to the "induction proof" part of this answer for a proof of your claim without the fluff):

> **Exercise:** Prove by induction that for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, there exists an $m$ so that $H_m\geq n$. Conclude that as $m\to\infty$, $H_m\to\infty$.

*Proof.* In order to see that the harmonic series diverges, it is enough to show that, for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, there exists an $m$ such that $H_m\geq n$. To see this, partition the series into groups, with each group totaling at least $1/2$ as follows:
$$
1+\frac{1}{2}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}}_{\geq 1/2}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{5}+\cdots+\frac{1}{8}}_{\geq 1/2}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{9}+\cdots+\frac{1}{16}}_{\geq 1/2}+\cdots.
$$
Now, the number of groups may be made as large as necessary. More formally, for each $k\geq 1$,
$$
\sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{i}\geq\sum_{i=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=(2^{k+1}-2^k)\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{2}.\tag{1}
$$
**Claim:** For each $p\geq 0$, 
$$
S(p) : H_{2^p}\geq 1+\frac{p}{2}.
$$
By proving this claim, which is your overall goal anyway, we will have proved what is desired in the exercise above, since for every $n$, choose $p$ so large that $1+\frac{p}{2}\geq n$, and then use $m=2^p$.

Below is an inductive proof of the claim above:

---

### Induction Proof

**Claim:** For each $p\geq 0$, $S(p) : H_{2^p}\geq 1+\frac{p}{2}$.

**Base step:** When $p=0$, $H_1\geq 1$, and this confirms that $S(0)$ is true.

**Induction step:** Fix some $\ell\geq0$, and assume that 
$$
S(\ell) : H_{2^\ell}\geq 1+\frac{\ell}{2}
$$ 
is true. To be shown is that $S(\ell+1)$ follows where
$$
S(\ell+1) : H_{2^{\ell+1}}\geq 1+\frac{\ell+1}{2}.
$$
Beginning with the left-hand side of $S(\ell+1)$,
\begin{align}
H_{2^{\ell+1}} &= H_{2^\ell}+\sum_{i=2^\ell+1}^{2^{\ell+1}}\frac{1}{i}\\[1em]
&\geq H_{2^\ell}+\frac{1}{2}\tag{by $(1)$}\\[1em]
&\geq 1+\frac{\ell}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\tag{by $S(\ell)$}\\[1em]
&= 1+\frac{\ell+1}{2},
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $S(\ell+1)$, completing the inductive step.

By mathematical induction, for every $p\geq 0$, the statement $S(p)$ is true. $\Box$

Thus, for every $n$, there exists an $m$ so that $H_m\geq n$. That is, $\lim_{m\to\infty}H_m=\infty$.

---

**Note:** If desired, you may also prove that, for $n\geq 1$, $H_{2^n}\leq 1+n$, an observation that allows you to conclude that (in light of the claim we just proved)
$$
1+\frac{n}{2}\leq H_{2^n}\leq 1+n.
$$

Comment: In my understanding what you answer was not part of the question, let alone the "*main* part." My reading of the phrase you quote is that this is given as motivation for the question. The  "but don't have any ideas" referring to obtaining the "Show that."

Comment: @quid Did you read all of OP's question? Did you read all of my answer? Your comment isn't very clear in my opinion.

Comment: Yes I read the question, and I browsed  your answer. What I meant to say is that I am under the impression that OP did in fact *not* ask for a proof of the lower bound for the harmonic number, but only for a proof of the  auxiliary claim given under "Show that." My reading of the sentence you quote at the start is that the proof of the bound for  harmonic numbers is *only* mentioned as context for the question under "Show that" so that a proof of that inequality for the harmonic numbers is not what is asked for.

Comment: To make my point more clear, I *believe* that the somewhat elliptic "but I have no ideas." is to be completed by "how to show this auxiliary claim" as opposed to "how to obtain the inequality for the harmonic numbers." In the end there is no harm done having the argument around. I still meant to point out my reading, as it might help you to see why none of the other answers, including the accepted one, addresses that broader point.

Comment: @quid Perhaps there could be some more clarity by OP, but his "Show that" question is couched in the context of proving $1+\frac{n}{2}\leq H_{2^n}$. It appears his "Show that" claim cropped up while trying to prove the lower bound for $H_{2^n}$. My answer is meant to address what *appears* to be his *main* question, ultimately proving the lower bound for $H_{2^n}$. He already has several answers for his basic "Show that" question--mine takes a broader view and looks at the overarching claim, not the auxiliary one.

Comment: I didnt ask for a proof of the harmonic inequality. However this proof of the inequality I did find helpful and interesting, so I wouldnt at all mind if you keep it (that is dont delete it). Whether it is inappropriate to answer a side question given only for context (I only included it because this would have gotten downvoted for lack of context) is a meta question which doenst concern me.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев Alright I will not delete it then. Glad you found it helpful and interesting.